# Make pycharm default for .py files in 14.04

Tags: software-installation, ide, python-2.7

I want to make pycharm ide default for all .py files in ubuntu 14.04. I have extracted the tar.gz file in my home directory but every time i have to run pycharm i have to go over to the bin subdirectory and run the pycharm.sh script.

is there any way to make it default application for .py files. As in **Right click->Open with Pycharm** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Follow these steps:

1. **Right-click** on the file, then choose **Properties**.
2. Click on the **Open With** tab on the **Properties** menu.
3. Select PyCharm from the list of applications, then click **Set as default**.